# How to get data from C# to Excel smoothly using VSTO and back again

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, dataset, vsto

I'm writing an application level add-in for Excel in C#.

The add-in is to be used for getting data from a foreign source (the add-in provides some GUI options for this etc.) into Excel. This data is not going to be updated and sent back to the data source or anything like that - although the user is of course free to edit the data in the local Excel application.

The data arrives in an XML format and currently I have used a code generation tool to be able to deserialize the xml documents into C# objects. The data follows a relational model.

The things I'm thinking about right now:

- Should I translate everything to a DataSet object with DataTables?
- If I've done that, how can I then get this data into an Excel sheet? Is it possible to e.g. create a table in excel and databind to my datatables/dataset?
- Really I don't think I want a "table" per se but just throw in the data into cells and the user can then work with the cells. Is it better then to just supply 2D arrays? But won't it be a pain to go from DataTable data rows to 2D arrays?

Some other questions as well...

- What is the easiest/best way to read data back from Excel to C#? I think I'd mostly be satisfied with just getting 2D arrays here. But traversing the "Range" objects seems cumbersome. Must be some better way?
- The sheet will likely have column names in the first row and then data in the rest of the rows. Is there any way for the C# code to recognize this when the user has selected the cells that make up my "table"? Or is this just something I'm going to have to take care of manually in the code?

I've never worked with this before so apologizing if some questions seem stupid. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any Google searches.. there are Tons of examples on how to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as well as with VSTO

Comment: I've googled a fair bit. I'm looking for best practice advice from people with experience. Solving the actual problem isn't hard, but I'd like to do it in an intelligent way.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Unfortunately, the signal to noise ratio is rather low for VSTO google queries (and for windows programming in general). I use VSTO regularly and rarely find answers to my questions on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why my question was downvoted... At least give reasons, how else can they become better next time around?

Anyway. The best solution, it seems to me, is to get my data into a DataSet and then create a ListObject in the Excel application and use it's data binding features to get my data into Excel.

Was not aware of this great control before.

Comment: I discovered that you can also directly bind data to `ListObjects` using LINQ: `listObject.SetDataBinding((from x in stuff select new { Foo = x.Foo, Bar = x.Bar }).ToList())`. The `SetDataBinding` method uses reflection over a `IList<object>` to construct the DataSet object. I use this a lot, and it is a great way to populate data quickly.

Comment: I took the liberty to expand my comment into an answer, in case someone stumbles upon the question in the future. VSTO resources are scarce.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some example from my previous work to open excel and get data from excel:
    public class ExcelModule
    {
        private Excel.Application excelApp;
        private Excel.Workbook excelBook;
        private Excel.Worksheet excelSheet;

```
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    public ExcelModule()
    {

    }

    public void OpenWorksheet(string fileName, int sheetNum)
    {
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
                0,
                true,
                5,
                "",
                "",
                true,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                "\t",
                false,
                false,
                0,
                true,
                1,
                0);
        excelSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(sheetNum);

    }

    public string GetValue(string cellAddress)
    {
        if (excelSheet.get_Range(cellAddress, cellAddress).Value2 != null)
            return excelSheet.get_Range(cellAddress, cellAddress).Value2.ToString();
        else
            return "";
    }

    public int Close()
    {
        excelApp.Quit();
        return 0;
    }

    ~ExcelModule()
    {
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

To write data into Excel you may use:

```
excelSheet.get_Range(cellAddress, cellAddress).Value2 = "your text";
```

Notes:
*I'm using VS10 with Office2007

Answer (score 1):

Using range along with 2d array in Excel will give you beter performance. Here as you are deserializing incoming xml to object, there is no need to convert it into dataset then to 2d array. Would recommend in view layer of your code you directly tranform your object to 2d array and then bind with range in excel sheet. For reading back read data into 2d array from range and then tranform it back to object which you can serialize and send it back to server. Now how effectively or exactly you use range or array will depend on how data in your sheet looks. To distinguish between header and data you may have a look at named range, it can be helpful.

Comment: Named range seems helpful. I may decide on this approach but I want to try with ListObject for now. The reason is I may want to use the data in other controls, I may want to maintain relations between tables in a nice way etc.

Answer (score 0):

Excel tables (aka "ListObjects") give you formatting for free, and they are easy to use. The corresponding type is `ListObject`.

You can use them with LINQ, without having to manufacture a `DataSet` object:

```
ListObject myTable; // usually declared somewhere else, eg. via the designer

var data = from x in myObjects select new
{
    Foo = x.Foo,
    Bar = x.Bar
};

myTable.SetDataBinding(data.ToList());
```

This will fill the table with your data using reflection. In the example above, you will have two columns titled Foo and Bar, and as many rows as you had elements in `myObjects`.

Of course, you can use more complex queries. In your case, using Linq to XML is probably a good idea. The point is that you can do exactly what you want in a handful of lines.

Also, you can put any `IList<object>` into `SetDataBinding`.